# How can I save the full expansion of a macro?

Tags: macros, expansion

I have the following definitions:

```
\newcount\tmpcounta

\def\convertletter#1{%
    \tmpcounta `#1\relax
    \ifnum\tmpcounta<`a{%
        \ifnum\tmpcounta<`A{%
            #1%
        }\else{%
            \ifnum\tmpcounta>`Z{%
                #1%
            }\else{%
                \advance\tmpcounta by -`A\relax
                \advance\tmpcounta by 26\relax
                \number\tmpcounta-%
            }\fi
        }\fi
    }\else{%
        \ifnum\tmpcounta>`z{%
            #1%
        }\else{%
            \advance\tmpcounta by -`a\relax
            \number\tmpcounta-%
        }\fi
    }\fi
}
```

and the following snippet

```
\usepackage{tikz}% for "foreach" and because I ultimately use it to draw stuff

\def\mylist#1{%
    \foreach \myitem in {#1} {%
        (\expandafter\convertletter\myitem)
    }
}

\mylist{a8,f12}
```

gives the expected output: [image: output as expected]. However, the following

```
\usepackage{tikz}

\def\mylist#1{%
    \foreach \myitem in {#1} {%
        \edef\myitem{\expandafter\convertletter\myitem}%
        (\myitem)
    }
}

\mylist{a8,f12}
```

does not seem to transform the input items at all: [image: unexpected output].

I ultimately want to process the result of `\expandafter\convertletter\myitem` further. That's why I tried to save it in a macro. But it seems I fundamentally misunderstand how macro expansion (and in particular `\edef`) works in TeX.

**Is there a way to save intermediate results in order to use them as inputs for other macros?**

Comment: you have assignments in your command, that is not expandable.

Comment: @egreg I expect `\convertletter` to convert `<letter><number>` into `<number>-<number>` and leave as is if it's already in that format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax for conditionals in TeX does *not* use braces. You should say

```
\ifnum\tmpcnta<`a
  do something
\else
  do something else
\fi
```

Anyway, your `\convertletter` macro uses assignments, so it cannot be used in `\edef`.

Here's an `expl3` implementation that's fully expandable.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\convertletter}{m}
 {
  \mdm_convertletter:N #1
 }

\cs_new:Nn \mdm_convertletter:N
 {
  \bool_if:nTF { \int_compare_p:n { `a <= `#1 <= `z } || \int_compare_p:n { `A <= `#1 <= `Z } }
   {
    \int_eval:n { \int_from_alph:n { #1 } - 1 } -
   }
   {
    #1
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\mylist}[1]{%
  \foreach \x in {#1} {%
    \edef\myitem{\expandafter\convertletter\x}%
    (\myitem)%
  }
}

\begin{document}

\mylist{a8,f12,111}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A “classical” implementation would be

```
\newcommand\convertletter[1]{%
  \ifnum`#1<`a
    \ifnum`#1<`A
      #1%
    \else
      \ifnum`#1>`Z
        #1%
      \else
        \the\numexpr`#1-`A-26\relax-%
      \fi
    \fi
  \else
    \ifnum`#1>`z
      #1%
    \else
      \the\numexpr`#1-`a\relax-%
    \fi
  \fi
}
```

You decide which one is easier.

With `\bool_if:nTF` we can use “boolean expressions”. The predicate form `` \int_compare_p:n { `a <= `#1 <= `z } `` returns true if the character code of `#1` is between the character codes of `a` and `z`; the connective `||` means “or”. The function `\int_from_alph:n` is case agnostic and returns 1 for `a` or `A`, 2 for `b` or `B` and so on.

Comment: @UlrichDiez I thought I had removed all `\tmpcnta` tokens. Fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can define your `\convertletter` macro using `\isinrange` auxiliary macro. Syntax of `\isinrange` is:

```
 \isinrange X(a-z)\iftrue  Yes, X is in a-z\else No, X isn't in a-z\fi
```

Then the `\convertleter` macro is defined more simple:

```
\def\isinrange #1(#2-#3)\iftrue{%
   \ifnum 1=\numexpr 0%
      \ifnum`#1<\numexpr`#3+1\relax
        \ifnum`#1>\numexpr`#2-1\relax 1\fi\fi \relax
}
\def\convertletter#1{%
   \isinrange#1(a-z)\iftrue \the\numexpr`#1-`a\relax-%
   \else \isinrange#1(A-Z)\iftrue \the\numexpr`#1-`A-26\relax-%
         \else #1%
   \fi\fi
}
```

Programming in TeX is a joy.